# getting api keys from module.exports

Tags: node.js

I have two files a config.js and main.js I am storing api keys in my config.js
like this

```
function getGoogleApiKey(){
  return 'KeyGoogle';
}
function getApiKey(){
  return 'keyApi'
}
function getApiKey2(){
  return 'keyApi2'
}

module.exports = {
  getGoogleApiKey,
  getApiKey,
  getApiKey2,

}
```

I would like to get specific keys from the config.js file when I need it. I want to use some keys on my main.js
Here is my main.js.

```
const {config} = require('./config.js');
const googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces(config.getGoogleApiKey, 'json');
const awesome = new awesome(config.getApiKey);
```

I am note sure how to get the keys, I also tried it in this way but I get errors.

```
const {getGoogleApiKey, getApiKey, getApiKey2} = require('./config.js');
const googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces(getGoogleApiKey, 'json');
```

Comment: `const config = require('./config.js');` ? What are the errors you get?

Comment: @Cristy Doesnt work.

Comment: @Cristy Mostly type errors of undefined variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
const {config} = require('./config.js');
```

is pulling out a `config` property from the value returned by `require('./config.js')`, which is non-existent in config.js.

Instead, just use this:

```
const config = require('./config.js');
```

which will assign the exported value (the `module.exports` object), and will work as expected.

Secondly, functions are being exported and not primitive (string) properties, so one or the other will need to be changed: export string properties directly *or* convert main.js to use the appropriate function call notation.

For example:

```
const googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces(config.getGoogleApiKey(), 'json');
const awesome = new awesome(config.getApiKey());
```